# Using multiple text colors in Android's textview [ Html.fromhtml() ]

Tags: android, html, android-layout, formatting, textview

In one textview I'm trying to separate text stylings on different words.

So far I have:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><small><font color=\"c5c5c5\">" + "Competitor ID: " + "</font></small></i>" + "<font color=\"47a842\">" + compID + "</font>"));
```

Basically, I'm saying I want `"Competitor ID:"` to be italic, small, and grey.

And I want that string `compID` to be normal sized, not italic, and green.

The italic and small portions of the code work perfectly, but for some reason, the entire text view has grey text, rather than just `"Competitor ID:"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out for working example http://javatechig.com/2013/04/07/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><small><font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + "Competitor ID: " + "</font></small></i>" + "<font color=\"#47a842\">" + compID + "</font>"));
```

Try the above.

Comment: @userIsAMonkey +1 great work but why are you using escape sequences in **font color** if it is in html

Comment: For peoples having issues; 
using color names doesn't work, I think you have to use color codes.

wrong:<font color=\"#white\">
right  :<font color=\"#f1f1f1\">

Comment: @MuhammadBabar the escape is because this is Java source code. To include a `"` in a Java String you have to escape it. After Java compiles this it'll look like normal HTML code and will be parsed as such by `fromHtml`.

Answer (score -8):

Try using one of these grey hex code values instead.

```
gray1 #030303   
gray2 #050505  
gray3 #080808     
gray4 #0A0A0A   
gray5 #0D0D0D
```

. Also try to control the text color inside the xml textview properties using the above codes. Hope this helps