# Can one have different colored text sentences in the same list view item in Android?

Tags: android

For example, look at this sentence:

> "I have to get on at A4 junction, And Getoff at B2 junction".

Here I want to change the color of

> "get on at A4 junction"

to blue in and

> "getOff at B2 junction"

and other words to white in the same listview item. Can anyone give me the solution for this problem?

Comment: Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392163/using-multiple-text-colors-in-androids-textview-html-fromhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Html.fromHtml

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html") );
```

Learn basic html for the colors.

Comment: but this can be used with textview . i want to know how to use with ListView item

Comment: write your strings you are going to populate the listviews with using html. It is the same.

Comment: but to populate the listview we are having ArrayAdapter<Strings>. Could we able to populate Arrayadapter<TextView> like this. And also we are having one XML file to define the layout of the listview. So how to populate the ListView items with textView . Can u write a sample code?

Comment: Do you know how to use custom listViews?

Comment: Not sure. Could you please help me ?

Comment: Here is a simple example http://android-helper.blogspot.jp/2011/07/android-custom-listview-example.html. In that example the listview has an imageview and textview. In your case you will just need the textview.

Comment: yah. i did it. great help.thnx bro