# How to change the color of a particular string in edit text on the fly??-Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, android-edittext, textcolor

In my app, I want the users to give their answers in the form of text through edit text. So for the correct answer I want the letters to turn green (or red for incorrect) on the fly while typing.

For example, if the answer is DOG, I want the the text to turn green if the user types DOG dynamically. Even if the the first letter he types is D then I want the text color to be green. Only when the user's input text is not correct do I want it to be red. The text color should change on the fly while typing.

Comment: You could try using:
[Using multiple text colors in Android's textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392163/using-multiple-text-colors-in-androids-textview-html-fromhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `EditText` and call [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) for it supplying custom `TextWatcher` where you mostly need to override its `onTextChanged`.

In this method change your text color according to your logic.

Snapshot :

```
    mEditBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_box_id);
    mEditBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

            String currentText = mEditBox.getText().toString();
            // highligt correct answer in green
            if ("DOG".startsWith(currentText)) { // user starts typing "DOG"
                mEditBox.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                mEditBox.setTextColor(Color.RED); // incorrect input
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: now when i run the app,at the first instance the text color is red for the answer "DOG" only when i erase it and type it again it turns green.so can u help me with a solution to change the text color at the first instance itself?

Comment: Do you mean your editbox contains "default" text DOG initially ?

Comment: nope. when I type DOG initially FOR the first time the text color is red. only wen I erase it and type again it turns green.

Comment: very strange, works fine for me. When do you call `addTextChangedListener` ? Can you make a breakpoint in `onTextChanged` and see that it is triggered when you start typing initially ?