# How to change color of individual letters in textView?

Tags: android, textview

I am displaying text in android like this:

```
TextView textview p new TextView(this);
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMethod());
textview.setText("Today: 2\nTomorrow: 8\nNext two weeks: 45");
textview.setTextSize(16);
textview.setTypeFace(null, TypeFace.BOLD);
setContentView(textview);
```

I want to make the 2, 8 and 45 from the text green while leaving the rest black. I know how to do it for all the text but not individual characters. Can someone help? I have looked through other similar questions but none seem to be setting the textview the way I am here.

Comment: Check out this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392163/using-multiple-text-colors-in-androids-textview-html-fromhtml

Comment: how can i use this if not using html to get the text but just have it commented in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
TextView textview p new TextView(this);
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMethod());
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("Today: <font color=green>2</font>\nTomorrow: <font color=green>8</font>\nNext two weeks: <font color=green>45</font>");
textview.setTextSize(16);
textview.setTypeFace(null, TypeFace.BOLD);
setContentView(textview);
```

This will set green colors to 2,8,45. simillarly you can use any html tags for textview text. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: hmm didnt work at all, should I be doing something other than just changing my code?

Answer (score 9):

Use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and add [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html)s to the text. You'll have to find the indexes of the charactes/substrings that you want to be spanned so you can call `addSpan`

```
SpannableString spannedText = new SpannableString(originalText);
int start = ..., end = ...;
spannedText.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```